# How can I use \hspace in fancyvrb package, without use the key space?

Tags: spacing, verbatim, fancyvrb

My minimal file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\bf]
\begin{document}
I want to  have indent in the amount of hspace{34pt} at 
the following line (without use the key space).
text text text text text 
And also I want to have indent in the amount of hspace{3pt} 
at the following line.
text text text text text 

Ordinary command .....
\parbox{12cm}{text text text text}
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Thank's.

Comment: and I presume you want the `\parbox{12cm}{text}` to still be printed verbatim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[
    numbers=left,
    fontsize=\bf,
    commandchars=\@\#\$,% <---------- <start cmd><start grp><end grp>
]
\begin{document}
I want to have indent in the amount of hspace{34pt} at 
the following line (without use the key space).
@hspace#34pt$text text text text text 
And also I want to have indent in the amount of hspace{3pt} 
at the following line.
@hspace#3pt$text text text text text 

Ordinary command .....
\parbox{12cm}{text text text text}
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Define three characters under `commandchars` key that you won't be using inside your verbatim text. Here I used `@`, `#`, and `$` for illustrative purposes. (Escape them with `\`)

The first commandchar defines the start of the command (originally `\` in `\hspace{3pt}`), the second commandchar defines the start of the group (originally `{` in `\hspace{3pt}`) and the third commandchar defines the end of the group (originally `}` in `\hspace{3pt}`).

The point here is to not choose `\`, `{` and `}` again since you are using them within Verbatim, à la `\parbox{...}`.

Comment: @ Troy Thanks my dear Troy. But how can LaTeX understand your purpose of using $ instead of  } ?

Comment: @SH.Madadpour I defined it in `commandchars=\@\#\$` keyval option of the `Verbatim` environment. (note the `\$`)